# Большое время tnsping

Tags: sql, oracle

Помогите разобраться в чем проблема, у tnsping время отклика от 7-20 сек. что это может быть ? и нормально ли это ? как это вылечить ? спасибо.

Comment: Это совершенно не нормально.
Где вы и сервер относительно друг друга (в одной сети, в разных локальных сетях, связь чрез интернет, связь не дай бог через спутник)?

Comment: @Smithson Скажу больше, помимо того что в одной подсети в 10 метрах от сервера. Но если запустить tnsping на серверном пк где стоит сама база время уменьшается максимум на 1сек (тоесть если на сервере 7 сек то на локальном пк 8 сек) и я не знаю куда копать

Comment: top на сервере что показывает? Может, там такая нехватка ОЗУ, что листенер валяется в свопе?

Comment: @Smithson у меня не на Linux крутиться, а на win 2008 server r2 Enterprice. И выбор ОС не от меня зависело, ОЗУ в поряде, сервер довольно мощный и ОЗУ = 16 гб

Comment: Таки ОЗУ точно хватает? Что показывет диспетчер задач по нагрузке на ОЗУ и на своп?

Comment: @Smithson 6гб занято из 16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение проблемы было следующим - переполнение лог файла **listener.log** после очистки время отклика составляет от 0-10 мс. Расположение файла **app\Oracle\diag\tnslsnr\имя\listener\trace**